# Failed review audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage

I just failed a review on this question.

I recommended moving the answer to SuperUser since this is obviously a software related issue and not a programming related issue.

["Cannot start Omnisharp because Mono version >=3.10.0 is required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991543/cannot-start-omnisharp-because-mono-version-3-10-0-is-required)

Comment: The reason you failed the audit, is because it's a well-received question that hasn't been closed or migrated, so the system thinks you should've voted "Looks ok". That's not a bug with the system. It's just that this question wasn't taken care of properly.

Answer (score 4):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

(emphasis mine)

Omnisharp is a development tool, so the question should not be migrated to Super User.